# Documentation of 'Risk-Adaptable Access Control (RAdAC)' of the NIST Computer Security Resource Center

Tags: documentation, amazon-iam

Due to goverment shutdown the related sites are shut down. I am writing partly writing my thesis on risk-based access control and the standard of the NIST is now not available to me.

Is anyone in possession of this document?
https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/events/privilege-management-workshop/documents/radac-paper0001.pdf

It would be a great help to me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what I was looking for, but luckily an internet archive saved it exactly once:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180422032008/https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/events/privilege-management-workshop/documents/radac-paper0001.pdf

Cheers!